# Jquery UI modal Dialog blocking background screen

Tags: css, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

I know this is very common question. I have to post it after researching solution on google alot. I am trying to open a Dialog with JqueryUI. I am trying to block background screen on opening dialog. I can get the dialog but I am unable to do the blocking background screen event after trying below scenarios:

1. added modal:true
2. updated latest version on jqueryui css

what would be my code issue.

```
$("#divDialog").dialog({
    modal: true
});
```

Any work around to fix the issue?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle?

Comment: very unfortunate. It works in jsfiddle for me. My bad it should be some css or js overriding my code. I have to check where it went wrong. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nd5w9/

The HTML:

```
<body>
  <button>Can't click when dialog shown</button>
  <div id="divDialog">Hi hi ih</div>
</body>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$("#divDialog").dialog({
  modal: true
});
```

When the dialog is shown, I can't click on the button. Are you sure the elements are being styled properly?